# How to rename multiple column whit different names by only name in r

Tags: r, multiple-columns, rename

I use a loop to merge several CSV files. In each file, there is a column that contains some info. The problem is that in some files, this column is called "IN FILE" and in other files, it is called "IN.FILE." or "IN FILE*". I would like to make things homogenous by renaming all these columns in "IN.FILE"

I tried to do this :

```
 if (grepl("IN FILE|IN.FILE.|IN FILE*", first_line)) {
colnames(df)[colnames(df) == "IN FILE"|"IN.FILE."|"IN FILE*"] <- "IN.FILE" }
```

Here, I try to replace all the wrong names with the right ones but the colname function doesn't accept multiple arguments. So, how to rename multiple column whit different names by only name in r ?

Answer (score 1):

If this is your data

```
df
  IN FILE IN.FILE. IN_FILE col IN FILE
1       1        1       1   1  1    1
2       2        2       2   2  2    2
3       3        3       3   3  3    3
```

Rename only those you wish through `grep`

```
colnames(df)[grep("IN.*FILE", colnames(df))] <- "IN.FILE"

df
  IN.FILE IN.FILE IN.FILE col IN FILE
1       1       1       1   1  1    1
2       2       2       2   2  2    2
3       3       3       3   3  3    3
```

but then you have duplicated column names. You can correct that by using

```
data.frame(df, check.names = T)
  IN.FILE IN.FILE.1 IN.FILE.2 col IN FILE
1       1         1         1   1  1    1
2       2         2         2   2  2    2
3       3         3         3   3  3    3
```

Answer (score -2):

After you read the excel file, you can reset the name of the columns by using the base R function "names"

```
names(df) <- c('column_1', 'column_2', 'column_3')
```

Make sure the vector  (after <- ) includes all the column names of the dataframe (as well as the order of the column names), including those that you don't want to reset the name.

Comment: I think the issue may be that OP wants to select a subset of column names and rename it.  The downvote could be based on your solution not addressing it.  Just my guess

Comment: This answer is generalized and does not answer the question. It should be a comment.

Comment: I might not get the question then. Saying you have a csv file with one column called "IN FILE"; another csv file with the column called "IN.FILE", last csv file with column "IN FILE*". You want to rename all the "IN.FILE" and "IN FILE*" columns with "IN FILE". My point is that: in your loop, after you read your file, you can rename the column name by ```names(df) <- c("IN FILE", other_non_related_column_1, other_non_related_column_2)```. That wasn't the answer you are looking for?